# ASP.NET core deploy to Azure not migrating database

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have been working all day by now to get my app deployed to Azure, but can't get it to work, while it previously worked like a charm.

At this point I even deleted the entire Webapp, database and database server.
I have updated some packages, but at this point there are no errors.

## Tools

I have put all the tools here that are installed. Maybe there might be a conflict that I am not aware of.

- ASP.NET Core >=1.0.1 and EF Core >=1.0.1
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Updates (incl ReSharper).
- Entity Framework 6.1.3 Tools for Visual Studio 2015
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003131 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.3 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003156 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.1.0 Preview 2.1-003177 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Version Manager (x64) 1.0.0-rc1
- Microsoft Azure App Service Tools v2.9.6 - Visual Studio 2015
- Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - v2.9.5.1
- Microsoft Azure Command Line Tools
- Microsoft Azure Libraries for .NET - v2.9
- Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9
- Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6
- Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0

### project.json

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServicesIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    "CsvHelper": "2.16.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.3",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-Verbonding-67a1a892-cfc3-493a-bb8c-5ddc0637d3db",
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

### web.config

These are the default settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>    
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=######;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

### bundleconfig.json

These are the default settings

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

### Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Verbonding.Data;
using Verbonding.Models;
using Verbonding.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Verbonding
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();

                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IHostingEnvironment env, 
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            var userManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService < UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context, userManager, Configuration["Password"]);
        }
    }
}
```

## Publish

### Connection

The connection settings are set by Visual Studio / Azure after connecting to Azure
[image: Connection]

### Settings

I thinks this is where it might go wrong.
There is a text saying `Discovering data contexts`. I would expect here to see my context class, but after a couple of seconds it stops and does not show anything
[image: Settings]

### Settings after discovering data contexts

The connection string is also added automatically by Visual Studio / Azure. I have checked the values in the connection string and they seem to be all right.
[image: Settings after discovering data contexts]

## Some things I have already tried:

### Update packages

Updating the packages to version 1.1.0. This did not have the desired effect. If anything it seemed to make things worse. In the end I ended up installing to version 1.0.1 to 1.0.3

### Clean installation on Azure

I removed the WebApp, database and database server and reinstalled them.

### Clean and rebuild the project

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project a couple of times, and even every time I made some changes. Did not solve anything.

### Add code to web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

This did not have any effect, but it also did not give any errors.

## Azure portal

I started looking at what happened at the Azure portal, here I noticed a couple of things.

### Web app deployed

The web app is deployed, but the database has not migrated. As long as I do not hit a page that needs to look into the database, everything works fine.

### Database queries

While there is nothing in the database (except for the default tables), there seem to be some queries executed.
[image: Database queries]

I really hope someone is seeing this and can tell me what is going on here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using EF Core migrations?

Comment: That is what I am looking for, but can't get it to work. Can you tell me what I would have to do?

Comment: According to your code, we could find that you call ``DbInitializer.Initialize()`` method to initiate the database at the end of the **Configure** method, please check the actual ConnectionString of context object that passed to Initialize method and make sure whether it connects to your Azure SQL database.

Comment: After trying a lot more, I just chose to make a new project and copy the classes I made so far. It works again.